# Shiny button stays active unless another button from same div is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

The following Shiny app has 3 buttons (blue when inactive). When a button is clicked (active) it should turn red until another button is clicked. If the user clicks elsewhere in the app (e.g. background, or any other widget than the buttons), the clicked button should stay red.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    
    # CSS
    tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
            .btn{
                color: white;
            }
            .item{
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            .active{
                background-color: red;
            }
        "))
    ),
    
    div(id = "buttons",
        actionButton(inputId = "button_1", label = "Button 1", class = "item"),
        actionButton(inputId = "button_2", label = "Button 2", class = "item"),
        actionButton(inputId = "button_3", label = "Button 3", class = "item")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # JS
    runjs(HTML("
        $('#buttons .item').on('click',function(){
            $('#buttons .item.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    "))
    
    session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This behaviour works in the snippet below but in the app the buttons do not turn red when clicked.

```js
$('#buttons .item').on('click',function(){
    $('#buttons .item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button{
  color: white;
}
.item{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <button class="item">Button 1</button>
  <button class="item">Button 2</button>
  <button class="item">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's already a class named `active` in Shiny which sets a background color to the buttons. So you have to use another name and use `!important`. And you don't need `HTML` in `runjs()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # CSS
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
            .btn{
                color: white;
            }
            .item{
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            .myactive{
                background-color: red !important;
            }
        "))
  ),
  
  div(id = "buttons",
      actionButton(inputId = "button_1", label = "Button 1", class = "item"),
      actionButton(inputId = "button_2", label = "Button 2", class = "item"),
      actionButton(inputId = "button_3", label = "Button 3", class = "item")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # JS
  runjs("
        $('#buttons .item').on('click',function(){
            $('#buttons .item.myactive').removeClass('myactive');
            $(this).addClass('myactive');
        });
    ")
  
  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```